# How to get the first link under a ul tag using Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors, puppeteer

I am trying to get the link of the latest house posting in a real estate website.

This is the code I have written til now

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const link =
  "https://www.daft.ie/property-for-rent/dublin-4-dublin?radius=5000&numBeds_from=2&numBeds_to=3&sort=publishDateDesc";

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(link);

  const elements = await page.$x("//button[normalize-space()='Accept All']");
  await elements[0].click();

  //   const handle = await page.waitForXPath("//ul[@data-testid='results']");
  //   const yourHref = await page.evaluate(
  //     (anchor) => anchor.getAttribute("href"),
  //     handle
  //   );

  const hrefs1 = await page.evaluate(() =>
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("a[href]"), (a) =>
      a.getAttribute("href")
    )
  );

  console.log(hrefs1);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

However, this code is to get all the `href` links on the target page.

HTML code of the page:

[image]

It is easier to read the code from the picture than if I paste the code, thats why I attached an image.

As you can see under `ul` tag with `data-testid=results` there are many `li` tags inside which there is a `a href`, I wish to extract the link from this and that too only the top most `li` link as it will newest house posting.

How can I do this?

Expected output - I just want the first link under `li` tag. In the picture above, the output would be

```
/for-rent/house-glencloy-road-whitehall-dublin-9/4072150
```

Comment: Do you just want the links under `data-testid="results"`? How about `document.querySelectorAll("[data-testid='results'] a[href]")`? If you only want the first one, then use `querySelector`. Ideally, please [edit] the post to show the output you expect, or the first 5-6 elements of it. It's hard to tell based on an linguistic description alone.

Comment: @ggorlen sorry for not writing the expected output on the first go, I made an edit for the same please have a look. Yes, I only want the first link under ```data-testid="results"```. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks--do my suggestion(s) above work for you?

Comment: @ggorlen So I tried ```document.querySelector("[data-testid='results'] a[href]")``` since I only want one but this returned ```undefined```

Comment: Weird. That selector works fine for me. Posted an answer to illustrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on the comment chain, the selector `'[data-testid="results"] a[href]'` should give the first result href.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^16.2.0

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const url =
    "https://www.daft.ie/property-for-rent/dublin-4-dublin?radius=5000&numBeds_from=2&numBeds_to=3&sort=publishDateDesc";
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const xp = "//button[normalize-space()='Accept All']";
  const cookiesBtn = await page.waitForXPath(xp);
  await cookiesBtn.click();
  const el = await page.waitForSelector('[data-testid="results"] a[href]');
  console.log(await el.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute("href")));
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```

If you want all of the result hrefs, try:

```js
const allHrefs = await page.$$eval(
  '[data-testid="results"] a[href]',
  els => els.map(e => e.getAttribute("href"))
);
```

Note that the data is available statically, so you could just use `fetch` (native on Node 18+) and Cheerio which is faster and probably more reliable, assuming there's no detection issues (and you could add a user-agent and take other counter-measures if there are):

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const url = "https://www.daft.ie/property-for-rent/dublin-4-dublin?radius=5000&numBeds_from=2&numBeds_to=3&sort=publishDateDesc";
fetch(url).then(res => res.text()).then(html => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(html);
  const sel = '[data-testid="results"] a[href]';
  console.log($(sel).attr("href"));

  // or all:
  console.log([...$(sel)].map(e => e.attribs.href));
});
```

On my slow machine this took 3.5 seconds versus 30 seconds for headful Puppeteer and 15-20 seconds for headless Puppeteer depending on cache warmth.

Or, if you are using Puppeteer for whatever reason, you could block all the requests, JS and images to speed things up dramatically. Your default `await page.goto(link);` waits for the load event, which is content you may not need.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fetch suggestion, you are right it is much faster than puppeteer.

Comment: Can you please tell me if I want to fetch all the result hrefs using cheerio, how do I do that?